# + operator with multiple parameters

Tags: ruby, parameters

In the code below I tried to change the + operator behavior. However it does not seem to accept multiple parameters unlike all other possible methods. Is this even possible in Ruby?

```
class A
  def add(a,b)
    p a
    p b
  end  

  def +(a, b)
    p a
    p b
  end  
end

@a = A.new
@a + 1, 3    # <<<< crash
@a.add 1, 3  # <<<< works
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You missed the `.` operator.

```
class A
  def add(a,b)
    p a
    p b
  end  

  def +(a, b)
    p a
    p b
  end  
end

@a = A.new
@a.+ 1, 3 
@a.add 1, 3 
# >> 1
# >> 3
# >> 1
# >> 3
```

Comment: Ah yes that works. Is there by any chance any way to do it without the extra dot?

Comment: @Napoleon No. `+` is either a unary or binary operator in Ruby, and not ternary. Whereas in `a.+ b, c`, `+` is just a method call, not an operator, and so can take any number of arguments.